# Largest power of "n" that divides a number completely

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can I write an Excel formula which will give me the largest power of `n` a value in a particular cell is completely divisible by?

Say

A4=1000

B2=2

`=SomeGeniusFormula(A4,B2)` returns 3 since 1000 is completely divisible by 2^3 but not 2^4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this array formula that literally test all the powers from 1 to 100 and then tests if the result of the division is a whole number by trying to equate the whole number to the return, then returning the highest power where that is true:

```
=MAX(IF(INT(A4/(B2^ROW(1:100)))=A4/(B2^ROW(1:100)),ROW(1:100)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

AGGREGATE can also be used:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(1:100)/(INT(A4/(B2^ROW(1:100)))=A4/(B2^ROW(1:100))),1)
```

This is normally entered.

---

If one has access to the new Dynamic Array formulas then replace `ROW(1:100)` with `SEQUENCE(100)`

```
=MAX(IF(INT(A4/(B2^SEQUENCE(100)))=A4/(B2^SEQUENCE(100)),SEQUENCE(100)))
```

And it is also normally entered.

Comment: Hi Scott, going by your first option, `=MAX(INDEX((MOD(A4/(B2^ROW(1:100)),1)=0)*ROW(1:100),))` would also work, and is entered normally :) + for the nice formula too.

Comment: @JvdV yes it would.

Comment: @JvdV here is another one, using dynamic arrays: `=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(100),MOD(A4/B2^SEQUENCE(100),1)=0),,-1),1)`

Comment: Wish I had access to these formulas :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(A4,POWER(B2,ROW(1:100)))=0))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(A4,B2^ROW(1:100))=0))
```

Replace the `100` within `ROW(1:100)` if to the power of 100 is insufficient in your real case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct calculation without array formulas or indexes:

```
=LN(GCD(A4,B2^INT(LN(A4)/LN(B2))))/LN(B2)
```

`INT(LN(A4)/LN(B2))` gets you the highest power of B2 you would need to try.

With your sample values, `INT(LN(1000)/LN(2))` would result in 9, since 2^9 <= 1000 < 2^10.

`B2^INT(LN(A4)/LN(B2))` results in the base value to that power.

With your sample values, it would result in 2^9 = 512.

`GCD(A4,B2^INT(LN(A4)/LN(B2)))` gets you the greatest common denominator of your original value and your base to its largest necessary power.

With your sample values, `GCD(1000,512)` results in 8.

`LN(GCD(A4,B2^INT(LN(A4)/LN(B2))))/LN(B2)` gets you the power that you would need to raise your base to, in order to get that greatest common denominator.

With your sample values, it results in LN(8)/LN(2) = 3. Thus, 2^3 is the greatest power of 2 that 1000 is divisible by.